# Problems while creating files with random file names while using std::ofstream in C++

Tags: c++, file, random, compiler-errors, ofstream

I have this code I am trying to make work (no duh right)  Right now it creates a single large file, but I want it to generate a series of randomly titled files.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>  

using namespace std;
string random(int len)
{
    string a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    string r;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) r.push_back(a.at(size_t(rand() % 62)));
    return r;
}

int main(){
    std::ofstream o("largefile.txt");

    o << random(999) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to add this, but I get an error about data types in `std::ofstream`

```
std::string file=random(1);
std::ofstream o(file);
```

Comment: if you are using c++03 then you have to do `std::ofstream o(file.c_str())` because `ofstream` doesn't have a constructor that takes a `string` before c++11, only a `const char*`.

Comment: Compiles just fine on my gcc version 4.6.3 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string file=random(1);
std::ofstream o(file);
```

should be:

```
std::string file=random(1);
std::ofstream o(file.c_str());
```

since `ofstream`'s constructor expects `const char*`.

---

Also consider using the following function instead of `rand() % 62`:

```
inline int irand(int min, int max) {
    return ((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1.0)) * (max - min + 1) + min;
}

...

srand(time(NULL));                    // <-- be careful not to call srand in loop
std::string r;
r.reserve(len);                       // <-- prevents exhaustive reallocation
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    r.push_back( a[irand(0,62)] );
```